# How do I send an embedded image email without ATT00001.bin file with c#

Tags: c#, html, smtp, smtpclient

I am able to send email via smtp with c#, whereby inserting images with LinkedResource.
The problem now is that the emails received contain ATT0000X.bin files as attachment. How do I make sure these bin files are not added in the email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue while trying to embed an image to the e-mail. I had two things wrong on my code, maybe one of them is happening to you:

1. First I was embedding an image but didn't define any tag for it to be displayed in my Body. This was fixed by adding into my HTML the tag cid:yourContentId and then assigning that tag as the image's ContentId. That fixed the issue in outlook, but it was still showing a clip like if the e-mail had an attachment, but no place to actually see the attachment. This looks super spammy. In Outlook web you could still see the ATT00001.bin attachment.
2. My second mistake was not defining the ContentType of my embedded image when creating the LinkedResource. This fixed the clip being displayed in the desktop client and in the web client no attachment could be seen anymore. The final code is something like this

   ```
       LinkedResource embeddedImage = new LinkedResource(imageStream, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("image/jpeg"));
       embeddedImage.ContentId = "ContentId";
       altview.LinkedResources.Add(embeddedImage);
       mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(altview);
   ```